# Excel, complex conditional formatting

Tags: excel

looking to have this result

[image]

have this data

[image]

need to configure the conditional formatting for this.

little confused as to how to write the formula
tried :

```
COUNTIF(Sheet2!$C$3:$C$5,$J6) +COUNTIF(Sheet2!$D$3:$D$5,">="&K$1) +COUNTIF(Sheet2!$E$3:$E$5,"<="&K$1)
```

Comment: Conditional formatting usually takes a formula that is a conditional (results in a true or false). The sum of `COUNTIF` results doesn't do that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic of the formatting. Why are the cells that are highlighted highlighted? What is the relationship to the start and end dates (I don't see one)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understood your problem. Does this help?

The formula obviously needs to be in the conditional formatting formula, not some cell, I just put it in the screenshot to show the corresponding ranges of my example more clearly.

In this example the "applies to"-area begins with B2
[image]

Comment: actually you got it right.  it works but not completely.  my mistake in not writing the right data.   assume i have a table where I register the days people take vacation.  'a' takes between 12/6 till 13/6  etc.   your formula works.  but what happens if in the same data table I have a multiple rows where the guy by the name "a" takes another vacation on 15/6.  so I have now two rows with data relevant to 'a'.  this does not work. I only see the first instance.

Comment: by the way.  I have this formula that looks like working BUT  I need it in the Google sheets and there its not working. any ideas? =SUMPRODUCT(($A$10:$A$15=$A2)*($A$10:$B$15<=B$1)*($C$10:$C$15>=B$1))

Comment: the formula doesnt return true/false, but 0, 1 or more. Add ">0" at the and to make sure it's true/false.Other than that this should work exactly the same as in excel, just make sure you select B2 as the upper leftmost cell for your conditional formatting (or adapt the formula if that's not the beginning of your table without title row/column). And don't forget the "=" at the beginning.